# RSpec: stop/stub after_create callback on factory level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am writing tests for a model which creates some files and folders on disk in a `after_create` callback. I would like to skip this in my model tests.

Normally, I would stub these callbacks in the spec which uses the factory, however, this model and factory are used as associations in many different specs. I would not want to repeat these same stubs in all those specs.

How can I set these stubs on the factory level, so I only have to define them once?

Comment: May be add an `attr_accessor :skip_create_callback` in your model and set it to `true` in your tests.

Comment: I'd rather not have test code mixed in with my 'production' code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in `spec_helper.rb` following code:

```
config.before(:each) do
  # your stubs
end
```